# How to leave the audio track as-is and just re-encode the video when using HandBrake?

Tags: audio, handbrake

I want to encode an MKV video to MP4 in HandBrake, but whenever I do this, the resulting video is fine but the audio is horrible - tons of scritchy high pitched artifacts.

How to I tell Handbrake (the GUI version, 1.1.2) to leave the audio track as-is and just add it into the output video without encoding it? Or, failing that, how to have it do a lossless audio encode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select one of the "Passthru" options as the audio track codec.

[image]

Read more here: https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/technical/audio-codecs.html

> **Passthru options**.
>
> HandBrake supports passthru for a limited number of popular source
> formats. These are: AC3, DTS, DTS-HD, TrueHD, MP3 or AAC (Passthru)
>
> This copies the audio bit-for-bit from the source so offers no loss in
> audio quality. These audio tracks can be quite large so can impact the
> final size of the output file quite substantially.
>
> **Auto Passthru**
>
> In the audio encoders list, there is an option called “Auto Passthru”.
> When encoding, this will automatically passthru any supported format
> to the source file. If the source format is not supported, or not
> supported in the output container, the fallback encoder will be used.
> The default is AAC.

Comment: Thanks for fleshing out the answer with images and quotes that explain things.

Comment: This was actually greyed out in the list for me, with the mkv I tried: I only had a couple of audio options like AAC and MP3.

Comment: What is your source audio encoded as? Per the documentation: "HandBrake supports passthru for a *limited* number of popular source formats."